# Restore Postgresql database from table files

Tags: postgresql, restore

Is it possible to restore a Postgres database when only having access to the table files under `$PGDATA/base/<db_oid>`? The system catalogs are empty.

*Background*

Somebody with `sudo` executed an `rm -Rf` under `/var/lib`. Random files where deleted, but not the ones of the database I am interested in. Postgres would not start, even after I restored several files/directories by hand. So I created a new `$PGDATA` and copied the database files in, hoping that Postgres would automatically read them. Apparently, Postgres relies a lot on its system catalogs to maintain links between what is on disk and what the user sees.

Comment: Without the commit log and the global tablespace, it will take an expert to extract anything.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound promising.  Do you know how you got into this predicament?

What specific system tables are empty?  A good chunk of the system catalogs are located inside `$PGDATA/base/<db_oid>`

Do you have any recent backups that could be used to splice together whatever it is that you are missing?

Of course the first step it to make a backup of the current state of things, so if you somehow make things even worse you can go back and try again.

Comment: Thanks! I 've updated the question with some background info.